# Why does `letter=="A" or "a"` always evaluate to True?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, or-operator

Please look at the code.  I'm using a robot car to draw a letter and in this code, when I type b, it will still draw small case a.

```
import create

# Draw a:
def drawa():
 #create robot
 robot = create.Create(4)
 #switch robot to full mode
 robot.toFullMode()
 for i in range(1280):
  robot.go(20,30)
 robot.stop()
 robot.move(-40,20)

# Draw b:
def drawb():
 #create robot
 robot = create.Create(4)
 #switch robot to full mode
 robot.toFullMode()
 robot.move(-100,20)
 for i in range(1270):
  robot.go(20,-30)
 robot.stop()

# Draw c:
def drawc():
 #create robot
 robot = create.Create(4)
 #switch robot to full mode
 robot.toFullMode()
 for i in range(700):
  robot.go(20,30)
 robot.stop()

# Define Main Function
def main():
 # While loop
 while(True):
  # Prompt user to enter a letter
  letter = raw_input("Please enter the letter you want to draw: ")
  # If user enters the letter a, draw a
  if letter=="A" or "a":
   drawa()
  # If user enters the letter b, draw b
  elif letter=="B" or "b":
   drawb();
  # If user enters the letter c, draw c
  elif letter=="C" or "c":
   drawc();
  # If user enters anything other than a letter from a-z,
  # ask them to enter a valid input
  else:
   print("Please enter a letter from a-z.")

main()
```

please help.

Comment: 1-space indent is horrible to read. Please use 4-space indent in the future as suggested in [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: 1 space is too small; 2 spaces are ideal; 3 are acceptable; 4 are orthodox; 5 were never used; 6 are gross; 7 are failure; 8 were in the beginning. i recommend to always use 2 spaces, and even proscribe that in python's syntax. it is part of the grammar of the language. i likewise doubt the utility of many other points raised in pep 8.

Answer (score 8):

It's because of your conditions. When you say...

```
if letter == "A" or "a"
```

...you are actually saying...

```
if it's true that 'letter' equals 'A', or is true that 'a'
```

... and `"a"`, as a non-empty string, evaluates always to true. You are not asking anything from `letter` in the right-hand side of the `or`. Do this:

```
if letter == "A" or letter == "a"
```

Or, since we're in python:

```
if letter in ["A", "a"]
```

Cheers!

Comment: A tuple (`letter in ('A', 'a')`) would actually be most idiomatic and slightly faster, but that's just nitpicking. I also like `x.strip().lower() == ...` when dealing with longer input, as it's very robust and short.

Comment: delnan, more than about being fast, it looks natural. But maybe that is just me!

Comment: (if letter == "A" or letter == "a") actually worked. 

Thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 1):

`if letter=="A" or "a":` is incorrect. Use `if letter == "A" or letter == "a":`

Your code evaluates to `if yourcondition or True` (a non-empty strng in a boolean context is true) which basically means `if True`.

Same applies to the other if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need semi-colons in Python.

Also, do `letter = letter.lower()`  so that you can simplify your case to `if letter = 'a':`

This works for me -

```
# Define Main Function
def main():
 # While loop
 while True:
  # Prompt user to enter a letter
  letter = raw_input("Please enter the letter you want to draw: ").lower()

  # If user enters the letter a, draw a
  if letter == "a":
    print "in A: %s" % letter
  # If user enters the letter b, draw b
  elif letter == "b":
    print "in B: %s" % letter
  # If user enters the letter c, draw c
  elif letter == "c":
    print "in C: %s" % letter
  # If user enters anything other than a letter from a-z,
  # ask them to enter a valid input
  else:
    print("Please enter a letter from a-z.")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letter == "B" or "b"
```

does not do what you think it does. It asks if letter is equal to "B" and, if not, it returns 'b'.

Do this instead:

```
letter.lower() == 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if letter in ('A', 'a'):
  drawa()
 # If user enters the letter b, draw b
 elif letter in ('B', 'b'):
  drawb()
```

This is how you should write it, the reasons have been given. Note that it should preferably be a tuple `('A', 'a')` and a not a list.

Comment: Why the down vote? At least leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `if/elif` statements -- for example the first `letter=="A" or "a"` logical expression is evaluated like this `((letter=="A") or ("a"))` because of [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operator%20precedence#summary) and so will always evaluate to `True` even if the letter isn't equal to an `"A"` (the `or "a"` part **is always True** because `"a"` isn't an empty string). There are a number of ways to fix that -- the simplest probably being to just change the expressions to follow this pattern `letter=="A" or letter=="a"` which is evaluated like this `((letter=="A") or (letter=="a"))`.

You could simplify the `if/elif/else` logic considerably using the technique shown in my [somewhat controversial] [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212435/better-writing-style-for-the-following-code/4214951#4214951) to a similar question. Applying it to what you're doing might result in something like the following:

```
import create

# Draw a:
def drawa():
 ...

# Draw b:
def drawb():
 ...

# Draw c:
def drawc():
 ...

# etc,,,

# Define Main Function
def main():
 while True:
  # Prompt user to enter a letter
  letter = raw_input("Please enter the letter you want to draw: ")
  if len(letter) > 0: 
   letter = letter[0].lower() # convert to lowercase and remove any excess
  # If first letter of what user entered was in the proper range, draw it
  if 'a' <= letter <= 'z':
   globals()['draw'+letter]()
  else: # otherwise ask them to try again
   print("Please enter a letter from a-z.")

main()
```

Comment: this is really nice code. it cuts down all the extra codings...lol
it works with all lowercase letters, but when i typed in uppercase letters, i get errors. i'll see if i can figure it out. thanks alot. :)

Comment: @arrgggg: Oops, sorry, fixed -- for uppercase letters it was trying to call `drawA()` instead of `drawa()` for example.