# Create variable name from two string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking to create a variable name from two strings in Python, e.g.:

```
 a = "column_number"
 b = "_url1"
```

and then be able to get a variable name `"column_number_url1"` that I can use.

I appreciate this is in general not a good idea - there are numerous posts which go into why it is a bad idea (e.g. [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python) , [Creating multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096604/creating-variables-in-python) )  - I mainly want to be able to do it because these are all variables which get defined elsewhere in the code, and want a easy way of being able to re-access them (i.e. rather than to create thousands of unique variables, which I agree a dictionary etc. would be better for).

As far as I can tell, the answers in the other posts I have found are all alternative ways of doing this, rather than how to create a variable name from two strings.

Comment: What's wrong with `a + b`?

Comment: what I want to have "a + b" as a variable name, so i could in theory go "a + b" = 5, and then have a variable with the name "a + b" with value 5

Comment: Use a dict and put a+b as key

Comment: That seems like a terrible idea, for exactly the reasons your research has already given you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
>>> a = "column_number"
>>> b = "_url1"
>>> x = 1234
>>> globals()[a + b] = x
>>> column_number_url1
1234
```

The reason that there aren't many posts explaining how to do this is because (as you might have gathered) it's *not a good idea*. I guarantee that your use case is no exception.

In case you didn't notice, `globals()` is essentially a dictionary of global variables. Which implies that you should be using a dictionary for this all along ;)

Comment: Perfect - thanks, while I do not disagree that this is probably a bad idea (and do not believe that I am "the one exception to the rule"), I am grateful for now knowing how to do it :-)

Comment: Oh I just meant a +1, I know you have to wait to accept it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary:

```
a = "column_number"
b = "_url1"
obj = {}
obj[a+b] = None
print obj #{"column_number_url1": None}
```

Alternatively, you could use `eval`, but remember to always watch yourself around usage of `eval`/`exec`:

```
a = "column_number"
b = "_url1"
exec(a+b+" = 0")
print column_number_url1 #0
```

<sup><sup><sup><sup>[`eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Joel's answer, a dictionary would be much nicer:

```
a = "column_number"
b = "_url1"
data = {}

data[a+b] = 42
```