# Is there a function operation to append the end of a variable name using a string?

Tags: python, variables, append

I am looking for a function to call that modifies the end of a variable name with a string, stored in an other variable. Is there a way to do this with a line of code, or do I need a for loop?

```
#For instance: Defined a string size, and floats to indicate the price for each size:
Size = 'M'
Price_S = 1.52
Price_M = 2.62
Price_L = 3.98

#Now I want to set a float cost to one of the price variables, depending on the value of Size:

cost = Price_(insert string from Size)

#So effectively it will be cost = price_M
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: don't do that. use dictionaries `{'S': 1.52, 'M': 2.62, 'L': 3.98}` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to change this I can think of is using a dictionary for the price. In your case this would look like this:

```
Size = 'M'
Price = {
'S': 1.52,
'M': 2.62,
'L': 3.98 
}

cost = Price[Size] #this will assign cost the value of 2.62
```

otherwise you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373618/create-variable-name-from-two-string-in-python) on the topic of setting a variable from two strings. But in general not good practice.