# Naming variable inside a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create 6 pandas dataframes from 6 text files. I want to name them according to the names of the text files. The text files are named as `'DAPC_min.txt'` and so on. I want the dataframe names as `'DAPC_data'` and so on.

```
import pandas as pd

lipids = ['DAPC', 'DIPC', 'DLPC', 'DOPC', 'DPPC', 'POPC']

for lipid in lipids:
    '{}_data'.format(lipid) = pd.read_csv(
        '{}_min.txt'.format(lipid),
        delimiter=' ', names=['bead_type', 'z_min', 'gz_min', 'dGwm'])
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
'{}_data'.format(lipid) = pd.read_csv(
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can try using a dictionary. Key is the file name and the DF is the value

Comment: You try to assign the values from the files to a string. What i would suggest is that you use a dict where the file names are the keys and the values well ... the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096604/creating-multiple-variables and others

Comment: I've added a duplicate which does this for excel worksheets. You can use the same for csv files.

Comment: Can someone please elaborate a bit? Checking the "original" answers only confused me.

Comment: @anotherone Define a dictionary to hold those variables outside the loop, say `dct = {}` and then inside the loop, change the left hand side to: `dct['{}_data'.format(lipid)] = pd.read_csv(...)` The way you are currently doing is possible in some languages (with some hacks in Python too) but using a dictionary in these situations is strongly recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.