# Converting "set var%number%=[value]" where 'number' changes value to a Python script

Tags: python

I have recently undertook converting all of my older batch files towards running on Python 3.6 to allow for them to run on multiple OS's. During this process I have hit a wall, my question is how to best convert these following batch commands to something capable of being run in Python. I have looked around extensively and it has all been for naught. I am open to suggestions.

```
set number=1
set var%number%=[some value here]
```

I have already tried things similar to this in Python:

```
number = 1
("var"+str(number)) = [some value here]
```

As well as this to try to get the interpreter to process the variable I'm going to assign to done before I attempt assignment.

```
number = 1
var = ("var"+str(number))
(var) = [some value here]
```

The reason why I am trying to convert the first method is so that the program could initially set a changing value to 'var1' then 'var2' then 'var3' etc. Is this one of those things that is unique to batch files and not languages such as Python?

Comment: `var` should be a proper list or dictionary; then you could just index it and assign values to its individual elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to change the value of `number` then set the value by
    number = 1
And change it again by doing the same
    number = 6

Edit: I see what you're trying to do, it is better not to do this in **Python** and you should try to avoid it for multiple reasons, but anyways here's an example of using `exec` (assuming `number` equals to `1`):

```
exec("var"+str(number)+"=0")
```

Which would run

```
var1=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096604/creating-multiple-variables) says, you could just do:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
for n in numbers:
    exec('var_%d = [20]' % n)
print(var_1) # prints [20]
print(var_2) # prints [20]    
print(var_3) # prints [20]
```

However, there are arguments against the usage of `exec` in that answer, so you should consider a dictionary. You can define as many keys (`var1`, `var2`, etc...) as you need.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = {}
    numbers = [1, 2, 3]
    for n in numbers:
        v['var' + str(n)] = 10 # initial value 10
    print(v['var1']) # 10
    print(v['var2']) # 10
    print(v['var3']) # 10

    v['var2'] = 20 # update value to 20
    print(v['var2']) # 20
```

Or if you need more customization, maybe consider defining your own class?

```
class MyVar(object):
    def set(self, number, value):
        setattr(self, 'var' + str(number), value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = 1
    v = MyVar()
    v.set(number , 20) 
    print(v.var1) # prints 20
    v.set(number , 40)
    print(v.var1) # now prints 40
    v.var1 = 50
    print(v.var1) # now prints 50
```

It's hard to recommend anything else without knowing more about what you want to do.

Comment: I couldn't really include a ton of detail as to what I want to do, because I have a whole bunch of varying applications for this question, and to be honest, I didn't even think about digging into defining classes and such. Thanks for your recommendations.