# Python: Assign Flexible Variables That Change Based on Value in Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I have a list: `test = ['0to50', '51to100', '101to200', '201to10000']`

I want to create the following four variables using a for loop:

```
var_0to50
var_51to100
var_101to200
var_201to10000
```

I tried the following code:

```
test = ['0to50', '51to100', '101to200', '201to10000']

for i in test:
    print (i)

    var_{i} = 3
```

But it gives me error:

```
File "<ipython-input-76-58f6edb37b90>", line 6
    var_{i} = 3
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cant make your python script write it self. This is what you try to do here

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a dict

```
test = ['0to50', '51to100', '101to200', '201to10000']
d = {x: 3 for x in test}
print(d)
```

output

```
{'0to50': 3, '51to100': 3, '101to200': 3, '201to10000': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you need a dictionary, instead of several dynamically named variables:

```
test = ['0to50', '51to100', '101to200', '201to10000']
dct = {}

for k in test:
    print(k)
    dct[k] = 3

print(dct)
    
# 0to50
# 51to100
# 101to200
# 201to10000
# {'0to50': 3, '51to100': 3, '101to200': 3, '201to10000': 3}
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/967621)
[Creating multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13096604/967621)