# How can I match input in a case insensitive manner?

Tags: python

I am currently making a MUD, or a SUD as we can call it (Singleplayer)
The only way to navigate through the game is to type commands.

```python
def level_01_room_01():
    choice = raw_input('>: ')
    if choice == 'north':
        level_01_room_02()
```

In this case, if the user enters North, with a capital N, the code will not perceive this command. It will be a big mess if I actually have to enter:

```python
def level_01_room_01():
    choice = raw_input('>: ')
    if choice == 'North':
        level_01_room_02()
    if choice == 'north':
        level_01_room_02()
    if choice == 'NORTH':
        level_01_room_02()
```

Etc.

Is there any way I can fix this, so that the player can type the word exactly as he or she wants to?

Comment: The usual python method for handling multiple choice questions is a dictionary, rather than a lot of if== tests.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594442/choosing-between-different-switch-case-replacements-in-python-dictionary-or-if

Answer (score 5):

Always `lower()` the user input before comparing it against your known strings (and always use lower case).

```
if choice.lower() =='north':
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
if choice.lower() == 'north':
    level_01_room_02()
```

(see [`str.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower))

Comment: Or, if there are other things to match against, consider using `choice = raw_input('>: ').lower()` so you don't need to call `lower` repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the methods `.lower()` and `.upper()` to convert strings to the respective cases.
A practical example would be lowercasing everything the user types like so:

```
def level_01_room_01():
choice = raw_input('>: ').lower()
if choice == 'north':
    level_01_room_02()
```

Since the input is always lowercased, as long as all your choices are coded in lower case (`"north"` and not `"NORTH"` or `"North"`) it will match correctly with the previously lowercased input.